# where eclipse preferences related to maven are stored

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I use eclipse indigo in my client's virtual machine. Every time I log in to the machine, all the user settings related to maven that are saved by me are getting vanished and I have to set everything again. Can any one please tell me where can I find the Eclipse/Preferences/usersettings of maven in machine so that I could preserve the files for future use. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that you refer to the preferences settings that are changed through Main Menu > Window > Preferences. Generally, without intimate knowledge about the respective plug-ins no definite answer about where the settings are stored can be given.

However, most of the settings provided by the preference pages are stored per workspace. You will very likely find files matching `org.eclipse.m2e.*.prefs` in the 
`<workspace directory>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` directory which hold the settings of the Maven plug-in.

Settings are not necessarily persisted after the preference dialog was confirmed. If plug-ins don't store them on disk explicitly they are stored not until the workbench is closed. And if the workbench terminates abnormally the settings changes might get lost.

If that doesn't help, please note down which settings exactly are lost.